# Cocoapod pod.lock file changes on pod install by adding a .git on the end of a repo url

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

So everything is fine with my pods, the project compiles successfully, the only issue im having is that when i do a `pod install` for some unknown reason, in the pod.lock file one of the repo urls gets changed from `https://blabla.com/repo-podspec` to `https://blabla.com/repo-podspec.git` which effectively changes nothing, except if i commit this to my git repo, my colleague has to do a `pod install` as well, and it changes it back to `https://blabla.com/repo-podspec`

So each time we commit to the repo we have to do a `pod install` that does nothing effectively which is quite annoying. Has anyone experienced something like this before? We have tried changing the repo url in the pod file to be with .git and without but it doesnt affect anything. (it is a locally hosted custom pod repo that hosts our own companies pod)

We are on the same version of cocoapods (1.5.3, yes its an older version, we cant upgrade yet) our Xcode versions do differ though slightly (10.1 vs 10.2.1) but I would think our Xcode versions wouldnt affect something like this. My colleague been having issues upgrading to the latest Xcode, so for now we cant change it.

Comment: Related issue with different symptom at https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/8931

Answer (score 0):

Somehow managed to solve it, i completely deleted my whole project, my colleague committed the pod.lock change, then after checking out the project fresh and installing everything from scratch it seemed to behave normally again. Whats odd was deleting all my pods and reinstalling didnt fix it, so not sure how this is really any different, but im just glad it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have your `pod repo list` in sync.

Read more about it here: https://willowtreeapps.com/ideas/how-to-fix-unexpected-podfile-lock-diffs-after-pod-install

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same issue and eventually found the solution.

The first time a developer does "pod install" it installs the Specs Repo onto your machine. When I did it, it used the URL listed in the "Podfile" source command which included ".git". However, a colleague had at some point done a manual "pod repo add" and used almost the same URL, but without the ".git" at the end. In other words, their URL differed from the "Podfile". This is what was causing the "Podfile.lock" to change between developers.

Here are the steps we used to solve the issue:

1. Run "pod repo list" on everyone's machine, so you can see the full URL of their Specs Repo. The name is not important, and I can not find any consistency on how the name is picked between developers' installations. Compare the URLs to the one in the "Podfile" and fix the repo list on those developers' machines. These Specs Repos are stored in the user's "~/.cocoapods/repos" directory, but you shouldn't need to concern yourself with that.
2. Have the developers with the incorrect URL remove their Specs Repo. Do this with the command "pod repo remove <<Specs Repo Name>>", with the <<Specs Repo Name>> replaced with the developer's Spec Repo name that you got from the "pod repo list". (As previously mentioned, it may not be consistent on everyone's machine.)
3. Once it is gone, you manually add the Specs Repo back in with the command "pod repo add <<Specs Repo Name>> <<URL>>". Replace <<Specs Repo Name>> with the name you want to give the Specs Repo, and <<URL>> with the correct URL. You might be able to just use "pod install" instead of the complicated command, but I have not had a chance to test that theory.